# Define function based on match

Tags: rust, closures

I have the following function, which runs fine:

```rust
use chrono_tz::Tz;
use chrono::{TimeZone, NaiveDate, NaiveDateTime};

fn my_func(time_zone: &str, fmt: &str, ndt: NaiveDateTime) {
    let datefmt_func = |ndt: NaiveDateTime| time_zone.parse::<Tz>().unwrap().from_utc_datetime(&ndt).format(fmt);
    let res = datefmt_func(ndt).to_string();
    println!("res: {res}");
}

fn main() {
    let time_zone = "UTC";
    let fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z";
    let ndt = NaiveDate::from_ymd_opt(2018, 9, 28).unwrap().and_hms_opt(2, 30, 0).unwrap();
    my_func(time_zone, fmt, ndt);
}
```

I'd like to let it accept `None` as `time_zone`. Within it, I need to repeatedly call `datefmt_func`, so I'd like to assign to `datefmt_func` once and reuse it. Here's what I've tried:

```rust
use chrono_tz::Tz;
use chrono::{TimeZone, NaiveDate, NaiveDateTime};

fn my_func(time_zone: Option<&str>, fmt: &str, ndt: NaiveDateTime) {
    let datefmt_func = match time_zone {
        Some(time_zone) => |ndt: NaiveDateTime| time_zone.parse::<Tz>().unwrap().from_utc_datetime(&ndt).format(fmt),
        None => |ndt: NaiveDateTime| ndt.format(fmt),
    };
    let res = datefmt_func(ndt).to_string();
    println!("res: {res}");
}

fn main() {
    let time_zone = Some("UTC");
    let fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z";
    let ndt = NaiveDate::from_ymd_opt(2018, 9, 28).unwrap().and_hms_opt(2, 30, 0).unwrap();
    my_func(time_zone, fmt, ndt);
}
```

However, this gives me

```
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
 --> src/main.rs:7:17
  |
5 |       let datefmt_func = match time_zone {
  |  ________________________-
6 | |         Some(time_zone) => |ndt: NaiveDateTime| time_zone.parse::<Tz>().unwrap().from_utc_datetime(&ndt).format(fmt),
  | |                            -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | |                            |
  | |                            the expected closure
  | |                            this is found to be of type `[closure@src/main.rs:6:28: 6:48]`
7 | |         None => |ndt: NaiveDateTime| ndt.format(fmt),
  | |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected closure, found a different closure
8 | |     };
  | |_____- `match` arms have incompatible types
  |
  = note: expected closure `[closure@src/main.rs:6:28: 6:48]`
             found closure `[closure@src/main.rs:7:17: 7:37]`
  = note: no two closures, even if identical, have the same type
  = help: consider boxing your closure and/or using it as a trait object

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `tmp` due to previous error
```

How can I adjust my code so that it will run? If "no two closures, even if identical, have the same type", then how can I assign a function which depends on a local variable (`time_zone`) to `datefmt_func`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as the compiler tells you, use trait objects and `Box` the closures:

```rust
fn my_func(time_zone: Option<&str>, fmt: &str, ndt: NaiveDateTime) {
    let datefmt_func: Box<dyn Fn(_) -> _> = match time_zone {
        Some(time_zone) => Box::new(|ndt: NaiveDateTime| {
            time_zone
                .parse::<Tz>()
                .unwrap()
                .from_utc_datetime(&ndt)
                .format(fmt)
        }),
        None => Box::new(|ndt: NaiveDateTime| ndt.format(fmt)),
    };
    let res = datefmt_func(ndt).to_string();
    println!("res: {res}");
}
```

Or in your simple example just run the code instead of creating a closure which you immediately call:

```rust
fn my_func(time_zone: Option<&str>, fmt: &str, ndt: NaiveDateTime) {
    let res = match time_zone {
        Some(time_zone) => time_zone
            .parse::<Tz>()
            .unwrap()
            .from_utc_datetime(&ndt)
            .format(fmt),
        None => ndt.format(fmt),
    }
    .to_string();
    println!("res: {res}");
}
```

Comment: This will likely be more expensive than branching each time.